# How to make sure map task node is always one of the input split node

Tags: hadoop

I am using hadoop map for doing image analysis but in a little bit unconventional way from what hadoop was designed to do. I am reading images from NAS instead of HDFS and analyzing them through a pre-compiled binary called by map task. Image location along with key is stored in a big text file and its split across multiple data nodes.

So if my input split is in node 2,3,4 and my map task is running in node 6, I am getting inaccurate result.

How can i make sure, that hadoop is scheduling map tasks such that map task node is always one of the input split node?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed. I'm curious why your your input split node must be same as the map task node. Or do you only need to know the location of the input split?

Comment: @zsxwing for some reason if the input split node is not the same as map task node, its not able to access the NAS drive... I gave the file location from NAS as its mounted on each data node but instead of trying to access from current data node, its trying to access from different data node.